# Django does not write to the database from form (not admin)

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Hi guys I have a little problem with Django 1.9. the class CreateView me not recorded in the database , the funny thing is that I did not throw any error, however added a code that validates form and asked to make a print (" Bad" ) console if the form is invalid. Every time sending the form (using POST) does not record anything and console, thanks to the setting you did, I printed 'bad ' . Now the problem is that the form is invalid, but can not find what is . Any ideas?

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import strategies


class FormCreateStgs(forms.ModelForm):

      ttlact = forms.CharField(
    widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'fs-anim-lower',
            'type': 'text',
            'placeholder': 'Las letras gritonas',
            'required': True, }))
cmpo = forms.CharField(
    widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'fs-anim-lower',
            'type': 'text',
            'placeholder': 'Escribe y selecciona...',
            'required': True, }))
aspc = forms.CharField(
    widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'fs-anim-lower',
            'type': 'text',
            'placeholder': 'Escribe y selecciona...',
            'required': True, }))
cpmt = forms.CharField(
    widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'fs-anim-lower',
            'type': 'text',
            'placeholder': 'Escribe y selecciona...',
            'required': True, }))
apzex = forms.CharField(
    widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'fs-anim-lower',
            'type': 'text',
            'placeholder': 'Escribe y selecciona...',
            'required': True, }))
espc = forms.CharField(
    widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'fs-anim-lower',
            'type': 'text', }))
mtrl = forms.CharField(
    widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'fs-anim-lower',
            'type': 'text',
            'placeholder': 'Las letras gritonas',
            'required': True, }))
sgcs = forms.CharField(
    widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'fs-anim-lower',
            'type': 'text',
            'placeholder': 'Las letras gritonas',
            'required': True, }))
obsv = forms.CharField(
    widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'fs-anim-lower',
            'type': 'text',
            'placeholder': 'Las letras gritonas',
            'required': True, }))
iecnc = forms.CharField(
    widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'fs-anim-lower',
            'type': 'text',
            'placeholder': 'Las letras gritonas',
            'required': True, }))
ieacvl = forms.CharField(
    widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'fs-anim-lower',
            'type': 'text',
            'placeholder': 'Las letras gritonas',
            'required': True, }))
iehbdz = forms.CharField(
    widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'fs-anim-lower',
            'type': 'text',
            'placeholder': 'Las letras gritonas',
            'required': True, }))

actini = forms.CharField(

    widget = forms.Textarea(
        attrs={
            'class': 'fs-anim-lower',
            'name': 'q12',
            'type': 'text',
            'placeholder': 'Las letras gritonas',
            'style': 'margin-bottom: 20px;',
            'required': True, }))
actdes = forms.CharField(

    widget = forms.Textarea(
        attrs={
            'class': 'fs-anim-lower',
            'name': 'q13',
            'type': 'text',
            'placeholder': 'Las letras gritonas',
            'style': 'margin-bottom: 20px;',
            'required': True, }))

actfnl = forms.CharField(

    widget = forms.Textarea(
        attrs={
            'class': 'fs-anim-lower',
            'name': 'q14',
            'type': 'text',
            'placeholder': 'Las letras gritonas',
            'style': 'margin-bottom: 20px;',
            'required': True, }))

class Meta:
    model = strategies
    exclude = ['ipU', 'nbrchg']
```

views.py

```
#from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from .models import strategies
from .forms import FormCreateStgs



crpt = 'hujpl\strategies'


class CreateStrategie(CreateView):
    model = strategies
    template_name = "%s\ctrStrategie.html" % (crpt)
    form_class = FormCreateStgs
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print("good")
        return super(CreateStrategie, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        print("BAD")
        return super(CreateStrategie, self).form_invalid(form)
```

template:

```html
<form id="myform" class="fs-form fs-form-full" autocomplete="off" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
     <ol class="fs-fields">
      <li>
       <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q1" data-info="Escribe tu tema o titulo">Título</label>
       {{form.ttlact}}
       <!--input class="fs-anim-lower" id="q1" name="q1" type="text" placeholder="Las letras gritonas" required/-->
      </li>
      <li>
       <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q2">Campo</label>
       {{form.cmpo}}
      </li>
      <li>
       <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q2">Competencia</label>
       {{form.cpmt}}
      </li>
      <li>
       <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q2">Aspecto</label>
       {{form.aspc}}
      </li>
      <li>
       <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q2">Aprendizaje Esperado</label>
       {{form.apzex}}
      </li>
      
      <li>
       <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q2">Sugerencias</label>
       {{form.sgcs}}
      </li>
      <li>
       <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q2">Observaciones</label>
       {{form.obsv}}
      </li>
      <li>
       <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q2">Indicador de Evaluación:</label>
       <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q2">Conocimientos</label>
       {{form.iecnc}}
       <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q2">Actitudes y Valores</label>
       {{form.ieacvl}}
       <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q2">Habilidades y Destrezas</label>
       {{form.iehbdz}}
      </li>
      <li>
       <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q2">Actividad</label>
       <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q2">Inicio</label>
       {{form.actini}}
       <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q2">Desarrollo</label>
       {{form.actdes}}
       <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q2">Final</label>
       {{form.actfnl}}
      </li>
      
     </ol><!-- /fs-fields -->
     <button class="fs-submit" type="submit">Guardar Actividad</button>
    </form>
```

It renders the template as well, even with the css and js .

Comment: Why don't you show `{{ form.errors }}` on the template, then you - and your users - will know why the form is invalid.

Comment: See (rendering form errors)[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages]

Answer (score 1):

You have instantiated a ModelForm without reference to the model. Perhaps you should be using a plain form like so:

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    # define fields
```

If you use a ModelForm you have to specify the model in a Meta internal class like so:

```
from . import models
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
      model = models.MyModel
      fields = ['field1', 'field2',]
```

Check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/ and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/ for more details. I would strongly recommend mastering the docs as they are world class.